# How to set hindi custom font for toasts in Android?

Tags: android, localization, typeface

I am creating an sms app in multiple languages. For Hindi, I have included the DroidHindi.ttf file in assets/fonts folder.  I am able to implement this in textview and button by using this:-

```
Typeface face;       
face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidHindi.ttf");
TextView font1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1font);
font1.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD); 
TextView font2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2font);
font2.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD); 
Button bfont = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
bfont.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
```

And it is working perfectly fine.

However, I am unable to implement it while displaying toast messages.

`Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.toast_msg ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Along with this code, I need to implement the DroidHindi.ttf file.

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text .setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD); // set your typeface here just like you have done above
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

first add this class

```
  public class typeFace extends TypefaceSpan {
    Typeface typeface;

    public typeFace(String family, Typeface typeface) {
        super(family);
        this.typeface = typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setTypeface(typeface);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setTypeface(typeface);
    }

}
```

and then simply use this methods

```
    public SpannableString spannableString(String string, String font) {

    SpannableString span = new SpannableString(string);
    span.setSpan(new typeFace("", Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/" + font + ".ttf")), 0, span.length(), span.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    return span;

}
```

call :

```
    textView.settext(spannableString("your text","DroidHindi"));
```

for toast :

```
    public void spannableToast(SpannableString text) {
    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

call :

```
spannableToast(spannableString("your text","DroidHindi"));
```

dont forget to add this code inside onCreate :

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
```